# Deleting Only the CoordinateSystem from the Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, resize, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to draw a tree on a Canvas with a coordinate system. I'm not yet that far that I could draw the tree itself, at the moment I'm trying to get the coordinate system a little bit more flexible, so it gets redrawn when I resize the window and the canvas within it.(That means expanding/reducing the axes of it, not the scale.)

I have already read some topics about canvas and the deleting of its children elements and I found a solution. The problem is that this solution does not work out that fine for me, because it keeps deleting only one line of the coordinate system on every resize event.

All lines that are used to draw the coordinate system got the UID starting with `CoordinateSystemIn`.

Currently my code for this is:

```
Canvas = Anzeige;
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainWindowLoaded)
    {
        foreach (UIElement Element in Anzeige.Children)
        {
            if (Element.Uid.StartsWith("CoordinateSystemIn"))
            {
                Anzeige.Children.Remove(Element);   
            }
        }
        Stift.DrawCoordinateSystem(Anzeige.ActualWidth, Anzeige.ActualHeight, 25);
    }
}
```

Is there any other solution which redraws the whole coordinate system at once and not only line for line at each resize event?

Comment: why not make the Canvas auto resize?

Comment: How is that meant? @Rang

Comment: i mean you may use ViewBox, but it seems could not solve you problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you `Canvas` in a `ViewBox` - the latter will automatically resize the canvas to the appropriate size. Your code could look like the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAccessControlFromResources.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas Width="80"
                Height="80">
            <Path Stroke="DarkGray">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" Center="40, 40" />
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="15, 40" EndPoint="65, 40" />
                        <LineGeometry StartPoint="40, 15" EndPoint="40, 65" />
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

This way you do not have to mess with the coordinates yourself.

**Update after Marv's comment**:

Actually, I think you should encapsulate your coordinate system in a separate class. This class would derive from `System.Windows.Controls.Panel` and would override the `ArrangeOverride` and `MeasureOverride` methods to position the child elements. Within these former method, you could also add / remove unnecessary `PathGeometries` that show the coordinate systems. The code could somewhat look like this:

```
public class CoordinateSystem : Panel
{
    // This element will display the actual coordinate system
    // It must be added to the collection of InternalChildren
    private Path _coordinateSystemPath;


    // This method is used to determine how much space the children want to have
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size infiniteSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
        Size desiredSize = new Size();

        // Measure how many space the items you want to display need
        foreach (var child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(infiniteSize);
            // Check at which position this child wants to be and
            // calculate the desired size of the coordinate system
        }
        return desiredSize;
    }

    // this method will arrange the path for the coordinate system as well as
    // all the children that will be displayed
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (var child in InternalChildren)
        {
            if (child == _coordinateSystemPath)
            {
                // Update the PathGeometry of this path according to provided finalSize here
                continue;
            }

            child.Arrange(child.DesiredSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is only a sketch and not the whole class. In this case you could also integrate zoom factor and translation of the point of origin of the coordinate system if you'd want to.

Anyway, while this solution is maybe the cleanest regarding Separation of Concerns, it also requires a good understanding about the WPF layout system and quite some work and testing. You can read more about this topic here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but this would only scale my coordinate system, im trying to expand the axes

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought that you meant `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` when you talked about coordinate system (not that you actually want to draw a path on the screen).

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I guess I will have to take a deeper look into the matter, because I just began the second year of my apprenticeship.
Anyway, thank you for your time & help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you might like to use is the [`Viewbox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx). This will do all of your resizing for you automatically (without a single line of procedural code). Take this example:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Path StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Data="M0,0 L25,25 M0,25 L25,0"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Here we have a simple `Path` 'X' to represent your `Canvas` content. It's quite small initially, or without the `Viewbox`, just 25 X 25 pixels. However, once inside a `Viewbox`, it can automatically fill its provided space. You might also find that the `Stretch` and `StretchDirection` properties are of use to you.

Just add your `Canvas` into a `ViewBox` and experiment with it to see if it will meet your needs.

Comment: Sounds more like OP just wants to draw longer or shorter coordinate system axes instead of just visually scaling the Canvas. Also think about tick marks.

Comment: I tried to use your Viewbox idea, but it makes my whole canvas dissapear.Am I doing something wrong? My wpf code looks like this now: 
    <Viewbox Name="viewbox1" Margin="6,38,6,1" >
            <Canvas Name="Anzeige" Background="Red" Margin="6,38,6,1" Opacity="1">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>

Comment: Edit: oh i see that the comments dont support code :S i hope you can read it anyway..

@Clemens you are correct i just try to expand the axes not the scale itself